# Storing hex values in a map .. java?

Tags: java, hashmap, hex

I am currently doing it like this.. but it gets actually stored as integer.. How can i do it?

commandMap = new HashMap();
commandMap.put("SET_DISPLAY", 0xD0);
commandMap.put("READ_ADC", 0xD1);
commandMap.put("GET_PARAM", 0xD2);
commandMap.put("SET_PARAM", 0xD3);
commandMap.put("GET_IOVALUE", 0xD4);
commandMap.put("SET_IOVALUE", 0xD5);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Decimal, hex, octal and so on are just notations; i.e. different ways of rendering an integer in characters.  They are not special kinds of numbers.

So ...

```
commandMap = new HashMap(); 
commandMap.put("SET_DISPLAY", 0xD0);
int value = commandMap.get("SET_DISPLAY");
System.err.println("0x" + Integer.toHexString(value));
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no separate "hex" data type.  If you want to display values as hexidecimal you can use the static method `Integer.toHexString(int i)`.

Even though they're stored as integers, you can still do things like

```
if (commandMap.get(command) == 0xD2) {
    ...
}
```

so there's really no need to have a separate data type.

Comment: yup...you are right.. i din have any idea dealing with hex and stuff...anywaay...now i ve got  clear picture..thanks... :)